# MFE webpack config causing Undefined reading call

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-module-federation

After restructure my configs directory and config file entries in the webpack configs, I'm getting error in my HOST application when trying to import Remote Application. Host app was working as intended before the restructure. is there anything to do with the nested /src/ folder?

[image: Error]

**the working structure before refactoring**

```
- /
- /remote
-    /bootstrap
-    /app
-    /index
-    /webpack.config.js
- /host
-    /bootstrap
-    /app
-    /index
-    /webpack.config.js
```

**the structure after refactoring that causes the undefined (reading 'call')**

```
- /
- /remote/src
-    /bootstrap
-    /app
-    /index
- /host/src
-    /bootstrap
-    /app
-    /index
- /configs
-    /webpack.remote.js
-    /webpack.host.js
```

**In general unchanged files**

```
index.ts
import './App.tsx'

App.tsx (Actual Application Component)
    -- HOST import Box from 'mfe/Box'
    -- REMOTE export Box()

Bootstrap.tsx (Used for mounting the Remote MFE without host)
    - import './App'
    - mount App to DOM
```

Below are the restructured webpack config files with only the file path changed in the following properties

1. entry from: ./src/App.tsx to ./{folder}/src/App.tsx
2. HtmlWebPackPlugin.template: from /src/index.html to /{folder}/src/index.html
3. remote mfe config

   ```
     -- from
     exposes: {
       "./App": "./src/index.ts"
     },
     -- to
     exposes: {
       "./App": "./remote/src/index.ts"
     },
   ```

-- webpack host config

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");

const deps = require("./host/package.json").dependencies;
module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: './host/src/App.tsx',
  output: {
    publicPath: "http://localhost:5000/",
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ["*", ".tsx", ".ts", ".jsx", ".js", ".json"],
  },

  devServer: {
    port: 5000,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        type: "javascript/auto",
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|s[ac]ss)$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "host",
      // filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      remotes: {
        'module': "remote@http://localhost:5001/remoteEntry.js"
      },
      exposes: {},
    }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./host/src/index.html",
    }),
  ],
};
```

-- webpack remote

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");

const deps = require("./remote/package.json").dependencies;
module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./remote/src/Bootstrap.tsx",
  output: {
    publicPath: "http://localhost:5001/",
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".jsx", ".js", ".json"],
  },

  devServer: {
    port: 5001,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        type: "javascript/auto",
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|s[ac]ss)$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "remote",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "./App": "./remote/src/index.ts"
      },
      shared: {
        ...deps,
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps.react,
        },
        "react-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
        },
      },
    }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./remote/src/index.html",
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: I need the restructure like this to share node_module/libs and components across multiple MFEs without using monorepo

Comment: tried using context to set root, not working